# WifiManager doesn't connect properly when the Wifi Open has no internet

Tags: java, android, wifimanager, wifi

I'm trying to connect to a WiFi (open network) which couldn't have Internet access and I having some problems with this.

When the Wifi has internet, my code work 100% for all devices. But, when the Wifi has no internet, some devices doesn't respond my code (below) correctly.

```
List<WifiConfiguration> wifiConfigurations = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();

int i = -1;
for (WifiConfiguration iWifiConfig : wifiConfigurations) {
    String wifiConfigSSID = iWifiConfig.SSID.replace("\"", "");
    if (SSID_REGISTERED.equals(wifiConfigSSID)) {
        i = iWifiConfig.networkId;
    }
}

wifiManager.disconnect();
//I already tried call "Thread.sleep(5000);" here.
wifiManager.enableNetwork(i, true);
//I already tried call "Thread.sleep(5000);" here.
wifiManager.reconnect();
//I already tried call "Thread.sleep(5000);" here.
```

I noticed I'm having problems in devices that show a confirmation dialog for Wifi without internet ([Dialog Wifi without Internet Confirmation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oToA.jpg)). In those devices, the reconnect doesn't return error, and the phone show that is connected at the Wifi, but I can't reach my server in the lan network.

For all other devices, that doesn't have this dialog confirmation, my code work 100%.

Comment: Do you want to know if device is connected to internet or not ? Like for example it can ping google or facebook ?

Comment: No, i just want to connect to Wifi. My problem is when the device check if Wifi has internet, in that case, the WifiManager doesn't really connect, the phone show I'm connected but I can't reach ips from the same LAN (like my server).